# What's wrong with my Depth Texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

At the moment I'm playing with FBO, which I don't really master. I have no problems with color atachments, but I can't figure out how to use depth textures in my render.
At the moment, I render my scene on a FBO (color+depth), then I draw a textured quad using the depth texture... But it doesn't work, my screen stays black (everyhting is 0 : even if i multiply by 1000 it stays at 0). (Depth test works : if I render the color texture instead of the depth, depth test works correctly)

Rendering loop :

```
///Render to FBO
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

FBO.Bind(); //Do I really need to explain what it does ?
glUseProgram(ShaderProgram->getProgramID());
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    ///Setting uniforms etc

mainScene.drawAll(); 


 //draw the quad

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glViewport(0, 0, m_window.getSize().x, m_window.getSize().y);

glUseProgram(2DShader.getProgramID());

quadModel.bindVAO();
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, FBO.DepthTexureID);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

And FBO creation :

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FBO_ID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FBO_ID);

    glGenTextures(1, &ColorBufferID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ColorBufferID);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, ColorBufferID, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);








glGenTextures(1, &DepthTexture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthTexture);
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
                glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, DepthTexture, 0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your depth texture is not mipmap-complete, but you are using the default mipmap filtering, so sampling will fail. Just specify some non-mipmapping filters like `GL_NEAREST` or `LINEAR` for sampling that texture.